# How to execute Haskell code in the context of Main with `stack`?

Tags: bash, unix, haskell, haskell-stack

I'm looking to do something like this

```
$ stack eval 'functionDefinedInMain $ 1 + 1' > test1.txt
```

However, when I execute that, `stderr` tells me

```
<interactive>:1:1: Not in scope: ‘functionDefinedInMain’
```

---

I've also tried to pipe code into `stack ghci`, which gets me closer:

```
$ echo 'functionDefinedInMain $ 1+1' | stack ghci > test2.txt
Using main module: 1. Package `exp-proj' component exe:exp-proj with main-is file: /home/wizek/sandbox/exp-proj/exp-proj/src/Main.hs
Configuring GHCi with the following packages: exp-proj

$ cat test2.txt
GHCi, version 7.10.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 5] Compiling Utils            ( /home/wizek/sandbox/exp-proj/exp-proj/src/Utils.hs, interpreted )
[2 of 5] Compiling Vertex           ( /home/wizek/sandbox/exp-proj/exp-proj/src/Vertex.hs, interpreted )
[3 of 5] Compiling Edge             ( /home/wizek/sandbox/exp-proj/exp-proj/src/Edge.hs, interpreted )
[4 of 5] Compiling Lib              ( /home/wizek/sandbox/exp-proj/exp-proj/src/Lib.hs, interpreted )
[5 of 5] Compiling Main             ( /home/wizek/sandbox/exp-proj/exp-proj/src/Main.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Utils, Vertex, Edge, Lib, Main.
*Main Edge Lib Utils Vertex> 3
*Main Edge Lib Utils Vertex> Leaving GHCi.
```

As you can see, the output (which is just the number `3` in this example) file is polluted by `GHCi`.

I'd like the content of the file to be instead:

```
$ cat test2.txt
3
```

---

How can I either

1. load all my project modules with `stack eval` as specified in my `.cabal` file to execute code in context, or
2. suppress GHCi output to `stdout`? (I don't mind if GHCi puts messages on `stderr`)

---

```
$ stack --version
Version 1.0.2, Git revision fa09a980d8bb3df88b2a9193cd9bf84cc6c419b3 (3084 commits) x86_64
```

---

**edit**: Added unix and bash tags since it might be possible to achieve this by piping together different `stack`/`GHCi` commands even without explicit support from `stack`.

Answer (score 3):

The `-e` flag in `ghc -e` expects a Haskell expression and has—by default—only access on `Prelude`. You need to use additional functions fully qualified:

```sh
stack eval 'Library.someFunc $ 1+1'
            ^^^^^^^^
```

However, this does only work in the following circumstances:

1. The module must be part of your **library**, not your **executable**.
2. The expression must be exported from the module.

If you're just trying to use `Main.xxx`, make sure that `Main` is a visible module in your library. This also concludes that you cannot use `eval` for executable only projects. However, this can lead to strange problems. For example, GHCi will try to import `Main` twice, once via the executable and once via the library.

### Example

```
$ stack new exp-eval simple
$ cd exp-eval
$ cat addition >> exp-eval.cabal
$ stack eval 'Main.main'
```

Where `addition` has the following content:

```
library
  hs-source-dirs:      src 
  exposed-modules:     Main
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
```

Comment: I've tried your first suggestion (`import Main`), and I got: `<no location info>:
    Could not find module ‘Main’
    It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.
`
Now I am trying the fully qualified version, and I am getting `<interactive>:1:52: Not in scope: ‘Main.functionDefinedInMain’`

Comment: I've tried it on a new project initialised with `stack new exp-eval simple`, without success: https://gist.github.com/Wizek/b79a47a02328fabae8da

Comment: Could you also post a shell session of yours demonstrating how you do it starting from `stack new ... simple`?

Comment: @Wizek: Sure. Sorry, the previous version of my answer was misleading. It only works for _libraries_ (which I tested locally), but I forgot to check whether the behaviour also holds for executables. It doesn't. `stack eval` only loads your library, not your executable. After all, your executable does not export any modules.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get what you want to do - do you want to execute the main - then use

```
$> stack runghc ./src/Main.hs > test.txt
```

or

```
$> stack build
$> stack exec -- modulename > test.txt
```

to invoke the compiled binary.

If you have a function that is exported in main it is easiest to use `stack ghci` and call the function from inside - if it produces a `String` you can then use

```
writeFile "test.txt" (myfunction parameter1 parameter2)
```

to get the desired result.

---

I have not used `stack eval` before but I guess you have to export your function in a library for that, I guess your cabal file says that you have only an export of an executable - to give you more info I would need your `cabal` file.

Comment: I think I get it - he wants to evaluate a string but with the definitions of the package/file in scope - I think it should work if you have the definitions in a library and just use `stack eval "import MyStuff; stuff ..." --package MyPackage`

Comment: @Carsten Yes, that is quite precisely what I'm trying to do. I'm trying out your suggestion of `stack eval "import MyStuff; stuff ..." --package MyPackage` without success yet, I get `<interactive>:1:41: Not in scope: ...` errors. I'll keep trying a bit more.

Comment: @Carsten: The `--package …` option isn't necessary if one executes `stack eval` in the package directory.

Comment: @Zeta ok thanks - was just a wild guess (cannot test right now)